# Is asking how to configure an IDE for debugging on topic?

Tags: discussion

I can't figure out how to configure Visual Studio Code to debug PHP with xdebug. Would it be on topic to ask here? I am looking for a "How to" which actually works.

Comment: [so] would probably be better.

Comment: Closed as off topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264073/how-to-debug-php-in-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1#comment115383671_65264073

Comment: Well yeah, you're doing nothing more than asking for a guide, which would be off topic on [su] as well. If you want help then you'd have to show us what you have tried and ask *how* to finish setting it up correctly. Just asking us to go find documentation or products is off topic on most Stack sites.

Comment: I suppose that I could list 20 or 30 URLs to S.O questions, guides & tutorials, and why they fail. It seems easier, though, just to find the official VSC forum. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Just one guide would do, walk us through the steps, where everything stops working, what results you get. Then someone can say "oh yeah, do this..." or "you are missing this step" or even "you've got something misconfigured to begin with." Just shoving a bunch of links at us and telling us to distil them into something useful or find *yet another variant of the same thing* isn't really fair on people who give up their own free time to help you. Focused questions get more immediately useful answers.

Comment: That would be [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I have already been through it with my partner of a few decades who is also a developer. I guess that S.E is not the correct venue for such a question & will continue to search or ask elsewhere. Thanks for trying to help. Stay healthy